# Update Unauthorized with Angular and Nestjs

Tags: angular, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to send the data of this form to database, my backend funtions ok, but my frontend have a problem which show in code bellow.

[it's a wrong that i have when i try to save that in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbHuE.png)

It's my User.interface

```
export interface User {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  username?: string;
  email?: string;
  password?: string;
  role?: string;
  profileImage?: string;
}
```

It's my user.service.ts:

```
 updateOne(user: User): Observable<User> {
    console.log(user);
    return this.http.put('api/users/' + user.id, user);
  }
```

It's my update-user-profile.component.ts

```
update() {
    console.log('VALUE FORM: ', this.form?.getRawValue());
    this.userService.updateOne(this.form?.getRawValue()).subscribe(console.log);
  }
```

It's my update-user-profile.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="update()">
  <div>
    <mat-card class="container">
      <div style="width: 80%">
        <mat-card>
          <mat-card-content>
            <img
              *ngIf="form.get('profileImage')!.value"
              src="http://localhost:3000/api/users/profile-image/{{
                form.get('profileImage')!.value
              }}"
            />
            <ul>
              <li>
                <mat-progress-bar [value]="file.progress"></mat-progress-bar>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </mat-card-content>
          <mat-card-actions>
            <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="onClick()">
              <mat-icon>cloud_upload</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </mat-card-actions>
        </mat-card>
        <input
          type="file"
          #fileUpload
          id="fileUpload"
          name="fileUpload"
          accept="image/*"
          style="display: none"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="container" style="width: 80%">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="ID" formControlName="id" />
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" />
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Username" formControlName="username" />
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <p>
        To change the properties password and email, special logic is needed,
        this will come in later videos
      </p>
      <p>
        To change the profile image, takes some time to implement, will code in
        extra video
      </p>

      <button
        mat-flat-button
        color="primary"
        [disabled]="!form.valid"
        type="submit"
      >
        Update Profile
      </button>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</form>
```

Thanks !!!

I hope that this data will be saved in the database.

Comment: From your screenshots, We can see that you are calling the url `http://localhost:4200/api/users/12`. From experience, this port is the port for your angular local dev server. I suspect that this is not the port for your API. You might want to double check the port for your api and change the url in your `user.service.ts` for the complete url to your backend.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, i  create new file to use global the url like this                                                      {
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
} for that when I call the URL I call only API and the specific name of URL

Comment: I did not quite understood what you said, sorry. But clearly, from your screenshot, your code is calling `http://localhost:4200/api/users/12`, not `http://localhost:3000/api/users/12`. I think your problem is there.

Comment: If that's not the problem, then you might need to authenticate before doing your request. A 401 error usually mean the backend doesn't know who's calling it. I'm not sure how you handle authentication on your backend, but you might also need to check that.